# Separate IPs From Ports using Shell Script?

Tags: linux, shell

I was just wondering how I would go about writing a shell script to separate proxy IPs from their ports.

The proxies are stored in this format

```
ip:port
ip:port
ip:port
```

How can I use a shell script to separate the IP on the left side of the colon from the Port on the right side, and put the IP and Port lists in separate .txt files with the same order? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

If the proxies are listed that way in a file, say proxy.txt, then all you need is `cut`:

```
cut -f1 -d: proxy.txt > proxy_ip.txt
cut -f2 -d: proxy.txt > proxy_port.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

ips="1.2.3.4:123 2.3.4.5:356 4.5.6.7:576"
# or get IPs from stdin

# split them
ips_array=($ips)

for w in ${ips_array[@]} 
do
  echo $w | sed -e 's/:.*$//g' >> ips.txt
  echo $w | sed -e 's/^.*://g' >> ports.txt
done
```

Key is using the `($ips)` to split the list up.

---

EDIT:

I just realized that you didn't format your question correctly so it's not a single line with IP:PORTs separated by spaces, but one on a line by itself. You just need this then:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read w
do
  echo $w | sed -e 's/:.*$//g' >> ips.txt
  echo $w | sed -e 's/^.*://g' >> ports.txt
done
```

And you read from stdin.